# Glassfish server crashes Java after 30 or 60 minutes

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I'm setting up a Glassfish v3 server on an offline network on Redhat v6.  The server pretty much just runs Java Servlets with a lot of processing (The servlets are expected to run as long as 12 hours).  However, I've been having stability problems trying to get the software to run for long periods of time.  It seems that consistently, after 30 or 60 minutes (And no where in between) of running, Java will crash on the hosting machine, with the OS throwing an error message along the lines of "Process /java was killed by signal 11".  The Glassfish log and the JVM log will not have any details of why it stopped abruptly.

It seems like a timeout issue, since it always happens at 30 or 60 minutes, and I've tried adjusting session timeouts, request timeouts, and idle thread pool timeouts, but none of them seem to be doing the trick.  I've tried running the Java code segment that's doing the bulk of the work outside of Glassfish and just as a Java main method, and it runs to completion just fine.  Has anybody else seen an issue like this?  Where Glassfish causes java to crash after a specific amount of time?  Thank you!

Comment: I'd say that something else in your OS is killinkg GF. Maybe some task running every 30 or 60 minutes that kills any task consuming resources above a certain threshold? What do GF logs say about it?

Comment: My GF log doesn't say anything.  No error messages or anything.  The software prints some text to the log as part of its normal operation, and it'll have some of that text in the log as if it were halted mid execution.  I would be more inclined to believe that it might be some other task running every 30 or 60 minutes, except that it's exactly 30 or 60 minutes from the start of the server.  If it were some crashing on some other clock, it would probably be interrupted at other intervals like 38 minutes, or 50 minutes, by chance.